# Seems we can only use the conditional operators (? :) in AutoMapper with ProjectTo - is there anyway to use a switch expression instead?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper, projection

I have a few mappings like:

```cs
CreateMap<TrophyTransfer, TrophyTransferSaveDto>()       
   .ForMember(x => x.ReceiverName, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => 
     y.ReceiverType == TrophyOwnerTypes.ExhibitionMuseum
     ? y.ExhibitionMuseum!.Name
     : y.ReceiverType == TrophyOwnerTypes.TaxidermyWorkshop
         ? y.TaxidermyWorkshop!.Name
         : y.Owner!.Name));
```

this is working fine but it's not readable at all, also this is a simple example imagine having 5-6 other conditions here ...

I want to use a switch expression or at least if/else to write this mapping but because this
(`MapFrom`) needs an expression I can't do that.

something like :

```cs
 return y => y.ReceiverType switch
 {
    TrophyOwnerTypes.ExhibitionMuseum => y.ExhibitionMuseum!.Name,
    TrophyOwnerTypes.TaxidermyWorkshop => y.TaxidermyWorkshop!.Name,
    _ => y.Owner!.Name
 };
```

also, I did try the other overload of `MapFrom((src, dest))` that accepts a `Func` but I **can't** use this because of the Projection part. **(the `ProjectTo<>` method)**

Is there a better way to write these mappings alongside the projection feature?

Comment: Compiler cannot generate ExpressionTree for switch. So you have to stay with conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

the typical approach I use is to map across the explicit values then have an unmapped property with the logic to be assessed when the property is accessed / serialized:

```
[Serializable]
public class TrophyTransferSaveDto
{
    // ...
    public TrophyOwnerTypes ReceiverType { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public string ExhibitionMuseumName { get; set; } 
    public string TaxidermyWorkshopName { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverName 
    {
        get { return ReceiverType == TrophyOwnerTypes.ExhibitionMuseum 
            ? ExhibitionMuseumName 
            : ReceiverType == TrophyOwnerTypes.TaxidermyWorkshop 
                ? TaxidermyWorkshowName
                : OwnerName
    }
}
```

Then map the various names from their sources, which will be #null where those relations don't exist. ReceiverName would be mapped as `Ignore`. It probably should handle where the Name associated with the ReceiverType is #null, where there is an invalid data combination.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. the main reason I have conditional operators in the mappings like the above example is generating appropriate SQL queries. I was looking for a feature that looks like doesn't exist in auto mapper that allows me to write this better.